# Remove LAST blank line from a text file containing paragraphs using notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

How to remove the last blank line from the following example using a Regx and notepad++?

```
qwerty
asdfgh
<blank line>
zxcvbn
poiuyr
<last blank line>
```

The text example contains blank lines between the blocks of text.

I thought a 'lookaround' regx might work, for example: (?s)(?=.*)\n, but it seems to find all end of line characters and not the last one.

Comment: Why do you need to do this with a regex?

Comment: I have many file to process.

Comment: Glad my answer worked for you. Please also consider upvotng the answer(s) that turned helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a generic

```
\R\z
```

It will match  a linebreak and the end of file.

Depending on your file line break style, you may use

```
\r\n\z
\r\z
\n\z
\r?\n\z
```

As `\R` is a shorthand for `\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]`, you may also use

```
(?:\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029])\z
(?:\x{000D}\x{000A}|[\x{000A}\x{000B}\x{000C}\x{000D}\x{0085}\x{2028}\x{2029}])\z
```

Or, if `\z` is not supported:

```
(?:\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029])$(?![\s\S])
(?:\x{000D}\x{000A}|[\x{000A}\x{000B}\x{000C}\x{000D}\x{0085}\x{2028}\x{2029}])$(?![\s\S])
```

The `$(?![\s\S])` matches end of a line/string with no char after it allowed.

Comment: This is a little off-topic, but some regx engines do not support \R or \z. The Boost library Regex++ used by Emeditor for example will not work with \R\z. So it would be interesting to find a generic solution that works with most engines.

Comment: Did you mean \x{000A} as opposed to \u000A ? \u means upper case characters and not unicode Hex

Comment: @w2kpro In Notepad++, use `\x{XXXX}` notation. You mentioned some other editors, and there `\u` notation may work.

Answer (score 0):

try this `\n\Z` to delete all empty las lines, and if you need only one try `\n\z`

Comment: That works on notepad++, but some of the other text editors are a bit quirky. On Textpad7 it only finds the \n after the very first block of text. On Emeditor in the advanced find/replace settings form, the number of extra lines has to be set to a value greater than the nember of lines in the file (which is unwanted behaviour). The following code seems to work on most editors: (?:\n)$(?![\s\S])